# Shared resource re-establishment between threads

Tags: python, synchronization, python-multithreading

I am trying to figure out the correct way to handle the following scenario with synchronization in python. Say there is a shared resource `connection` which is used by 8 threads to issue commands over a connection. Occasionally, `connection` goes stale and will throw exceptions for which I added an exception handling routine which can re-establish the connection.

The issue is such that when the connection goes stale, all 8 threads will get the exceptions. To solve this, I can add a semaphore such that only one thread will try to re-establish the connection at a time, but even this has an issue as well.

If thread 1 is the first to acquire the semaphore, then threads 2-8 will soon be blocked on that semaphore when they encounter exceptions. Thread 1 will get a fresh connection which threads 2-8 can use successfully and will release the semaphore.

At this point, what I would like to happen is to have threads 2-8 being processing again, however, since they were previously blocked on the semaphore, thread 2 now becomes unblocked on the semaphore and tries to re-establish the connection *again* which thread 1 is now already trying to use. This can result is a cascading problem where threads keep trying to use the connection while other threads are trying to re-establish it. Is there a standard paradigm for dealing with a shared resource such as this?

Answer (score 0):

I would check whether the connection is established after any thread acquires a semaphore. If it's not then re-establish it, otherwise proceed as usual.